# where should I put oneSignal SDK file for https site in laravel 7 and how to refer them in blade file?

Tags: onesignal, laravel-7

I am integrating oneSignal notification for my site. This is my code. For now I make the setting as not fully Https site. And, I am successful on that. here is my code..

```
$content = array(
                 "en" => 'Tap here to see details.'                                      
                 );
                 
$headings = array(
                 "en" => $request->title                                    
                 );

$fields = array(
                'app_id' => '033bf006fe-1018-4e0e-bd82-683c004dc48137',
                'included_segments' => array('All'),                                            
                'contents' => $content,
                'headings'=> $headings,
                'url' => 'https://example.com/s/details/'.$slug,
                'chrome_web_image'=>'https://example.com/storage/app/public/scholarships/'.$imageName
                );

$fields = json_encode($fields);
print("\nJSON sent:\n");
print($fields);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                           'Authorization: Basic NWYyMDExNTYtZjBmOC00ZjBlLWFjN2EtND00M0OGY002OGIyMzUw'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And now I want to set for Https site. So I need to add the sdks files. Where should I add them and how to refer them on blade file?

This is how I refer the sdks file in my blade.php file

```
  <script src="{{asset('assets/frontend/js/OneSignalSDKWorker.js')}}"></script>
  <script src="{{asset('assets/frontend/js/OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js')}}"></script>
```